# how to set master layout from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way to call master layout view from controller?

have tried

```
public ActionResult Validate()
{    
    return view("~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml");    
}
```

but its not working.

Comment: I think you want to pass Layout Name in ViewBag, and assign it in the view

Answer (score 2):

Their is an overload in view method

```
return View ("NameOfView",masterName:"viewName");
```

Regard's
Shanker Paudel

Comment: hi shanker above one is showing me 

"The file "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderBody" method."

error message

Comment: try this syntax  return View("Index", "_Layout", null);